# If $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 = 0$ (here $a, b, h$ are real constants), then find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Question:**
If $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 = 0$ (Where $a, b, h$ are real constants), then find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.
Following choices are given:-

- $\dfrac yx$
- $\dfrac xy$
- $\dfrac {-y}x$
- $\dfrac {-x}y$

---

**My work:**
Differentiating the equation given,
$$2ax + 2h \left[y + x \dfrac{dy}{dx} \right] + 2by \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0 $$
$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-(ax+ hy)}{(hx+ by)}$$

Although I obtained $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, but there is no such option given. I need to write the answer is terms of $x$ and $y$ only.

I tried to find the value of $h$ from the given equation and substituted in the value of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ but that seems not working here. What would be the appropriate way to solve this question?

Comment: Why do you need to solve for $h$? You are given that $a, b$ and $h$ are constants. You found $\frac{dy}{dx}$ so you are done.

Comment: You want $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ in terms of $\frac{x}{y}$, $\frac{y}{x}$ etc? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Without the original source I cannot say, but your work is correct.

Comment: You should, because I am curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:**

From the given equation, we have:
$$ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 = 0 $$
$$\iff ax^2 + hxy + hxy + by^2 = 0 $$
$$\iff x(ax + hy) + y(hx + by) = 0 $$
$$\implies -\dfrac{ax + hy}{hx + by} = \dfrac{y}{x} $$

Thus, $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} =-\dfrac{ax + hy}{hx + by} = \dfrac{y}{x} $$
Hence option [A] is correct.

---

**Alternative thinking:**

$ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 = 0 $ is a combined equation of two straight lines passing through $(0, 0)$ and thus the equation can be written in the form,
$$(y - m_1 x) (y- m_2x) = 0$$

From here, we have:
$$m_1 = \dfrac{y}{x}\quad and \quad m_2 = \dfrac{y}{x}$$

Since $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is the slope of the tangent line of the curve, thus $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = m_1 = m_2 = \dfrac{y}{x}$.

Comment: I am not sure of the second approach. Your curve is a rotated ellipse, centred on the origin. I can't see why $m_1=m_2$ must hold at every point on the ellipse.

Comment: @C.Koca No, that's combined equation of two straight lines. Plot on desmos for some arbitrary a, b and h.

Comment: You multiply two straight lines. That gives you a conic.

Comment: @C.Koca multiplying two straight lines gives pair of straight line, not a conic ._.

Comment: @ryang ohh man, that's really confusing. I don't understand what's wrong with the second method. (Also both the methods are giving same result). The answer for the given question is $\frac y x$ indeed.

Comment: 1. When eqn A $⟹$ eqn B, then A has at most as many solutions as B; when eqn A $⟺$ eqn B, then A and B have the same solution set; [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4419769/21813)'s a visual illustration.$\quad$2. In your third mathjax step, the implication ought to go only in the *reverse* direction; notice that $(0,0)$ satisfies the original equation but not the fourth mathjax line.$\quad$3. Notice also that when $a,h,b$ are all $1,\;\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}|_{x=0}=−1≠\dfrac yx.\quad$4. The original eqn indeed represents a conic, including the straight-line(s) degenerate conics.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the original equation by $x^2$ to obtain $b(\frac{y}{x})^2+2h\frac{y}{x}+a=0$.  Its solution is of the form $y=mx$ where $m$ is a constant satisfying $bm^2+2hm+a=0$. So $\frac{dy}{dx}=m=\frac{y}{x}$. Hence the first option is correct.

Answer (score 1):

dividing by $xy$, and setting $z = \frac{y}{x}$, we get:

$bz^2 + 2hz + a = 0 \implies z = \frac{-2h \pm \sqrt{4h^2 - 4a}}{2b}$

Since $z = \frac{y}{x} = c$ is a constant, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is also equal to $c$ which is same as $\frac{y}{x}$.