# Determining the domain of a logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I constructed two examples of determining the doamin of a logarithmic equation:

**Example 1**

$$\ln\left(3\,a-x\right)\,\ln\left(2\,x+2\,a-5\right)=\ln\left(3\,a-x\right)\,\ln\left(x-a\right)\\
\ln\left(3\,a-x\right)\,\left(\ln\left(2\,x+2\,a-5\right)-\ln\left(x-a\right)\right)=0\\
\ln\left(3\,a-x\right)=0\quad \textbf{or} \quad\ln\left(2\,x+2\,a-5\right)-\ln\left(x-a\right)=0$$

For the right-side equation $$\ln\left(2\,x+2\,a-5\right)=\ln\left(x-a\right),$$ we should insist that $2x+2a-5>0\;$ ***AND*** $\;x-a>0.$

**Example 2**

$$\log_{3}\left(a-x^{2}\right)=\log_{3}\left(a-y^{2}\right)\\
a-x^{2}=a-y^{2}$$

Here, it should be enough to insist that $a-x^{2}>0\;$ ***OR*** $\;a-y^{2}>0$, because these both sides are equal, and if one of them is greater than zero then the other one is automatically also greater than zero.

---

Why, with the first example, must we use ***AND***, yet with second example, it is enough to use ***OR***? I tried using the ***OR*** method in the first example, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Example 1** $$\ln\left(2\,x+2\,a-5\right)=\ln\left(x-a\right),$$ we should insist that $2x+2a-5>0\;$ ***AND*** $\;x-a>0.$

> **Example 2** $$a-x^{2}=a-y^{2}$$ Here, it should be enough to insist that $a-x^{2}>0\;$ ***OR*** $\;a-y^{2}>0$

In fact, the above '***AND***' and '***OR***' can *both* be dropped (just choose the simpler expression to specify as positive), because generally, \begin{align}&\color{red}{\ln f(x)=\ln g(x)}
\\\iff{}& f(x)=g(x)\quad \text{and}\quad f(x)>0\quad \text{and}\quad g(x)>0
\\\color{red}{\iff}{}&\color{red}{f(x)=g(x)\quad \text{and}\quad f(x)>0.}\end{align}

Using Example 1 to illustrate this:

- \begin{align}&\ln\left(2x+2a-5\right)=\ln\left(x-a\right)\\
  \iff {}&2x+2a-5=x-a\quad\text{and}\color{violet}{\quad x-a>0}\\
  \iff {}&x=5-3a\quad\text{and}\quad x>a\\
  \iff {}&x=5-3a\quad\text{and}\quad 5-3a>a\\
  \iff {}&x=5-3a\quad\text{and}\quad a<1.25\end{align}
- \begin{align}&\ln\left(2x+2a-5\right)=\ln\left(x-a\right)\\
  \iff {}&2x+2a-5=x-a\quad\text{and}\quad \color{violet}{2x+2a-5>0}\\
  \iff {}&x=5-3a\quad\text{and}\quad x>2.5-a\\
  \iff {}&x=5-3a\quad\text{and}\quad 5-3a>2.5-a\\
  \iff {}&x=5-3a\quad\text{and}\quad a<1.25\end{align}
- [Desmos demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/93phn6dapv)

Of possible interest: the bottom example at [this Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4455560/21813).